# Flagging question without viewing it

Tags: discussion, flags

I just saw this question on the interesting tab.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103730/why-does-my-cat-suddenly-start-following-me-around-once-i-put-on-my-aphrodisiac

It was blatant that it was a joke (attempt) from the title, and the trending tag choice.

It would be nice to flag this question with out giving the OP the satisfaction of clicking into it.

Comment: Oh yeah, and *that* wouldn't get abused at all.

Comment: Although yes, these trolls are annoying, as @animuson wrote, this will be a "judge a book by its cover" type of abuse.

Comment: If the user is indeed a troll (as all evidence indicates), the downvote, rather than the view, is exactly the satisfaction he's looking for anyway.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to downvote before voting to delete!

Answer (score 6):

Since it's blatantly a troll, I don't think there's any harm clicking on it, as its view count isn't exactly going to be around for long. Besides, it could be someone just vandalised a completely valid post, and one wouldn't know with out looking.

On a sidenote, the same poster had https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103559/how-to-write-the-computer-code deleted (it's just quoting from Romeo and Juliet) - so it looks like they're abusing the site...

Comment: Probing the question ban algorithm?

Comment: ah vandals. Yeah, I wouldn't like it very much if my question was butchered and then closed as a result of it.

Comment: @Maudicus The summary of questions is confusing as well as to the name of the person - it's either the OP, an edit, or last person to answer... So without looking at it to get the context of edits/answers etc... I could see your suggestion leading to trouble.

Answer (score 1):

**No, this feature is not a good idea.**

A lot of question titles don't address or summarize  the actual question very well, making this feature open to abuse.

You are supposed to read at least *most* of a question before you flag.  Flagging based on the title alone is a *very* bad idea and will likely create more useless and wrong flags that the moderators will have to deal with.

What harm can there be in opening the question before flagging it?  The question will eventually get deleted (quite possibly the user too) and no one will ever know, except maybe 10k users.

Comment: I didn't use the feature tag... just wanted to discuss the question and bring the users behavior to more people's attention.  I don't take back that I would have flagged that question from the interesting feed and would have taken great satisfaction in doing so.

Comment: The point is, you shouldn't be able to flag something without looking at it.